# Disable Microsoft Edge Restore Pages Functionality

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, microsoft-edge

I scheduled a batch script with Task Scheduler to routinely close and reopen Edge to my website once a day while the browser is opened in Kiosk mode.

I have:

```
Taskkill /F /IM msedge.exe
:: wait three seconds and reopen dashboard in Edge
timeout /T 3
Start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --kiosk https://www.google.com/"
```

But when the webpage opens, I always see the Restore pages pop-up in the top right corner.
[image]

I would prefer that this pop-up either does not appear or automatically clicks the small `x` to make it disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As an alternative** approach, throw in the `--no-session-restore` parameter with the `Start` command for the `msedge.exe` argument.

```
Start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --no-session-restore --kiosk https://www.google.com/"
```

---

**Otherwise**, run the following PowerShell command as an administrator to set the registry value for the current user, preventing Microsoft Edge from restoring open pages after unexpected or forceful termination.

### PowerShell

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\" -Name "HideRestoreDialogEnabled" -PropertyType DWord -Value 00000001 -Force
```

### Command Line

**Note:** *Run this admin elevated as well.*

```
reg add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge" /v "HideRestoreDialogEnabled" /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f
```

**Please note** the "related resources" show `HKLM` and related path and values of keys to set. This is applicable from Microsoft Edge version 100 onward for policy-level configurations.

If you are using a compatible version of Windows, you can use `gpedit.msc` to configure these policies but you may need to download the latest policy definitions and load them.

Otherwise, you can just set the applicable registry keys for `HKLM` with the example PowerShell and command line provided for the `HKCU`—I can confirm `HKCU` works and suggest it.

## Related Resources

- [Getting sick of "Restore Window" prompt](https://www.reddit.com/r/MicrosoftEdge/comments/vqpbtv/getting_sick_of_restore_window_prompt/)
- [Enable or Disable Restore Pages Dialog Prompt in Microsoft Edge](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/enable-or-disable-restore-pages-dialog-prompt-in-microsoft-edge.14883/)
- [HideRestoreDialogEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#hiderestoredialogenabled)